# Open and send message via React native application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sms

i need to open the native SMS app from my react native app . Once opened, the user will find the text and the number already set and ready. I found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms but it only works for android and i need it to be also for iOS. Any help please

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible on iOS. ([See reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1).)

To open another application use the [Linking API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html).

You can do the thing you want on Android, and on iOS at least open the sms app with a blank text intended for the chosen recipient.

`import {Linking, Platform} from 'react-native'`

…

```
const url = (Platform.OS === 'android')
  ? 'sms:1-408-555-1212?body=yourMessage'
  : 'sms:1-408-555-1212'

Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
  if (!supported) {
    console.log('Unsupported url: ' + url)
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(url)
  }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))
```

Comment: For iOS you can use: const separator = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '&' : '?'
    const url = `sms:${phoneNumber}${separator}body=${message}`

Answer (score 1):

You'd want something that binds to the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, there's a package called [React Native Message Composer](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-message-composer) on GitHub that asserts it does that but appears to no longer be actively maintained.